# How to deal with inaccuracies of HLSL SampleLevel on Radeon GPUs/Drivers?

Tags: gpu, hlsl, texture-mapping, direct3d11

I stumbled on an precision issue when it comes to texture sampling on my Laptop (MacBook Pro with Bootcamp and Windows10, Radeon Pro 560) which is not appearing on my Desktop (Windows7, nVidia GeForce GTX 1070) using Direct3D11.

In order to analyze the issue I created a 16x16 checkerboard texture and draw a fullscreen rect using said texture and a nearest-point-sampler with the following pixelshader:

```
float4 PS_Test(PSIn input) : SV_TARGET
{
  float v0 = in0.Load(int3(input.uv * 16.0f, 0));
  float v1 = in0.SampleLevel(samplerPoint, input.uv, 0);
  return (v0 == v1) ? float4(0, 1, 0, 1) : float4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

I would expect v0 being always equal to v1 which is the case on my desktop (GeForce) but NOT on my laptop (Radeon). The latter produces vertical and horizontal lines now and then (not on every texel though). [See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN1c2.png)

I suspect an accuracy problem in the hardware or driver. 
For my purpose I rely on exact texture adressing which works with Load, but I would prefer to use the SampleLevel-method if possible. How could I best solve the issue ? I played with adding a tiny offset like 1e-6f to the UVs, but no success.

Comment: Are `v1` and `v0` completely different (so both have a different value of the checkerboard) or is just a small delta on the correct value making them unequal?

Comment: If you need  an exact texture lookup you have to ensure that the interpolated `uv` coordinates wont fall on the pixel borders. So you need to choose an offset for the `uv` coordinates that represents the half of the pixel dimension of the texture in the texture lookup.